# Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

Why am I getting this error for this code? I have the correct imports for ArrayList an Collections

```
private ArrayList<String> tips;

public TipsTask(ArrayList<String> tips){
    this.tips = Collections.shuffle(tips);
}
```

Comment: Hint: *what is the method signature for Collections.shuffle*? In particular, noting the error message (which says "it's not possible to assign void/nothing to an ArrayList variable"), what does shuffle return? The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) should sufficiently answer this question. With type errors, *always* check the relevant definitions/types first - there is no question, only incorrect usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Collections.shuffle(tips);
```

Collections.shuffle return void, you cannot assign void to a `ArrayList`.

you could do for example:

```
    Collections.shuffle(tips);
    this.tips = tips;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Collections.shuffle` method doesn't return anything.

You can try this:

```
private ArrayList<String> tips;

public TipsTask(ArrayList<String> tips){
    this.tips = new ArrayList<String>(tips);
    Collections.shuffle(this.tips);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Collections.shuffle` shuffles the array in-place. This will be sufficient:

```
private ArrayList<String> tips;

public TipsTask(ArrayList<String> tips){
    this.tips = tips;
    Collections.shuffle(tips);
}
```

Or if you don't want the original list to change:

```
private ArrayList<String> tips;

public TipsTask(ArrayList<String> tips){
    this.tips = new ArrayList<String>(tips);
    Collections.shuffle(this.tips);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.shuffle(tips)` returns void. So you cannot assign this to an `ArrayList()`

What you want is

```
private ArrayList<String> tips;

public TipsTask(ArrayList<String> _tips){
    Collections.shuffle(_tips);
    this.tips = _tips;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call it like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> tips;

public TipsTask(ArrayList<String> tips){
    this.tips = tips;
    Collections.shuffle(tips);
}
```

Collections.shuffle(tips) modifies the ArrayList directly. It does not need to create a copy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write it like this:

```
private List<String> tips;

public TipsTask(List<String> tips) {
    this.tips = new ArrayList<String>(tips);
    Collections.shuffle(this.tips);
}
```

The other way breaks making the List private.  The person with the original reference can manipulate your private state.